# Redirect domain but keep original url

Tags: linux, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2, mod-proxy

I'm trying to use .htaccess with the proxy tag to redirect owncloud.example.com to owncloud.example.com:7777/owncloud but i need the url in the adressbar to remain unchanged.

This is my current htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^owncloud\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://owncloud.example.com:7777/owncloud [P,L]
```

However with this configuration I get Proxy Error 502 when i try to browse to the web page.

I have mod_rewrite and mod_proxy enabled.

Comment: When you visit `http://owncloud.example.com:7777/owncloud`, directly does the URL stay that way? Are there any errors? If it's on the same machine, why not just use `http://localhost:7777/owncloud`?

Comment: if i visit that url it works, but i want to be able to connect without having to type the port and not seeing it in the adress bar. I have it working so that i get directed to that port and then it works, but i want to not be able to see for port.

Comment: You didn't quite answer my question.

Comment: The error im getting when i try to connect is https://imgur.com/gallery/zlR8s

Comment: And on some browsers it show error "502 proxy error". When i visit the url it becomes "http://owncloud.example.com:7777/owncloud/index.php/login", and it's not on the same machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it needs the rest of the path info. You may also need to configure owncloud so that it thinks it's at `http://owncloud.example.com/`. Try this:

```
RewriteRule .* http://owncloud.example.com:7777/owncloud/$0 [P,L]
```

Comment: Try'd it out and it does work like that but it still changes the URL to http://owncloud.example.com:7777/owncloud/index.php/login instead of http://owncloud.example.com. Any other ideas ?

Comment: Like I said, configure owncloud to think it's at the other address.

Comment: And how would i do that ? I dont see and option in the config files for that

Comment: This any help? https://doc.owncloud.org/server/latest/admin_manual/configuration_server/reverse_proxy_configuration.html

Comment: Sorry about the lack of response but i do not have the time to look this week. Thanks for the suggestion and i will be sure to check it out and reply back.

Comment: Ok, i know it took a long time to reply but im glad to say that it turned out that this worked :D. Thanks for sticking with me !