# Keep original URL after redirection by domain provider

Tags: apache, apache2

## Goal

`fharrell.com/*` is redirected by the domain provider to `hbiostat.org/blog/*`.  I want to keep the address bar showing `fharrell.com/*`

## Apache2 Setup

- `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` is standard with the following exception:

```
<Directory /home/ubuntu/htdocs/>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

- `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/hbiostat.org.conf` is symbolically linked from `/etc/apache2/sites-available/hbiostat.org.conf`
- `hbiostat.org.conf` sets the document root as `/home/ubuntu/htdocs` which has been working well for some time
- Contents of `hbiostat.org.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin my@email.address
    DocumentRoot /home/ubuntu/htdocs
    ServerName  hbiostat.org
    ServerAlias www.hbiostat.org
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

<Directory /home/ubuntu/htdocs>
  Options FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride None
  Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /home/ubuntu/htdocs/blog>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^hbiostat\.org/blog$ fharrell.com [R]
</Directory>
       Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/hbiostat.org/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/hbiostat.org/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName hbiostat.org
ServerAlias www.hbiostat.org
DocumentRoot /home/ubuntu/htdocs
<Directory /home/ubuntu/htdocs/blog>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^hbiostat\.org/blog$ fharrell.com [R]
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Systax was checked using `sudo apachectl -t`.
I checked that mod rewrite is active using `sudo a2enmod rewrite` and restarted the server with `sudo systemctl restart apache2`

But this has no effect, with `hbiostat.org/blog/*` remaining in the addressbar.

Tried:
Many remedies on stackoverflow.com (including the two below) and elsewhere, including putting the commands into an `.htaccess` file (I'd like to avoid the `.htaccess` approach).

Any help appreciated.

---

[Redirect domain but keep original url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40740738/redirect-domain-but-keep-original-url)

[Redirect subfolder URL but keep original domain name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28142942/redirect-subfolder-url-but-keep-original-domain-name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't make the browser display a different domain after a 30x redirect.

mod_rewrite doesn't do what you're thinking it does.

Comment: Will correctly pointed me away from this approach.  My solution was to put the static web site files onto netlify.com (at fharrell.netlify.app)  using manual deploy, then having my domain provider point to netlify's customized DNS servers.  This keeps the original URLs.